# Best Approach to Store Sensitive Information on Database and retrieve it

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, security

What is the best approach to store and retrieve sensitive information on a database? We are busy building an ASP.Net Core MVC application, but the requirement is to enable connection to multiple or different databases to integrate to and from, but we want to configure and test the connection at runtime. Thus, we need to somehow store this data source's credentials securely without compromising security.

Comment: you should probably clarify whether you are talking about the connection string(s) or the user logins.  (or both?)  Also whether the databases are on different servers and/or if they are in the same domain.

Comment: The idea is to get info to be able to build a connection string so that the application is able to connect to any database on any server. The application will need to be able to cater for different servers, probably within the same domain for now. The application will also be written to be able to interface with API's in the near future, so I'd rather try to use an API to get integration data from different domains. Not sure if you can get to a SQL server outside of the domain without having a security risk?

Comment: I'd agree with you. Best to use API with proper user authentication... don't expose connection strings.  It's also useful to restrict the app pool identity's access to the database to only the functions the most privileged app user would have.  (ex: might not want the app to be able to delete a whole table.... It might prevent EF from doing some migrations but you should apply those manually anyway... it should still generate the script(s) which you can run from the server's admin account.

Comment: If you are storing user-input client-side that will be used for the connection string it's problematic.  The best you can do is encrypt it using as key something specific to the machine like serial number of the user's machine.  Microsoft has a built-in mechanism for this.   (I think it's called "DPAPI")  That'll ensure that if the data is stolen, it can only be unencrypted on the user's machine.   If the user's machine is compromised all bets are off... a malicious executable could read memory, unencrypt, etc...